# sap.m.List: Remove Separators and Start Each Item with Bullet

Tags: sapui5

Below is my code: It generates a list with a horizontal separator after every item (Gives a feeling like the rows of the table).
I wish to display it like this instead:

> Permissions:
>
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3

Even if bullet is not possible, at least, plain data one below the other would be nice. I do not want the separator in between.

```xml
<List id="PermissionsList"
  noDataText="NoPermissions"
  includeItemInSelection="true"
  items="{PermissionsList>/}"
>
  <headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
      <Title
        text="Permissions"
        level="H3"
      />
    </Toolbar>
  </headerToolbar>
  <StandardListItem title="{PermissionsList>Text}"/>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
<StandardListItem title="&#8226; {PermissionsList>Text}"/>
```

Which is the html code for bullet point. The alternative is adding a style class and using the `:before` selector to add whatever you like, it offers more flexibility in terms of styling.

To remove the separators, there's a flag for that:

```
showSeparators="None"
```

So the whole thing would be:

```
<List id="PermissionsList" showSeparators="None" noDataText="NoPermissions" items="{PermissionsList>/}" includeItemInSelection="true">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <content>
                <Title text="Permissions" level="H3"/>
            </content>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <StandardListItem title="&#8226; {PermissionsList>Text}"/>
</List>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jorg for your answer. showSeparators = "None" solved my issue. But  &bull; is not working for me. I get an error saying, entity not defined.

Comment: I just tried it with the html code instead of the html entity. `&#8226;` seems to work.

Comment: adding a css class and using the `:before` selector gives you more flexibility though.

Comment: @THI Does this answer solve the issue? If yes, please, don't forget to accept this answer.